# how to capture the event when html video tag is unmuted?

Tags: javascript, html, events, html5-video

I want to check if user has unmuted or muted the video. I am using video html tag.
Is it possible to detect if user has unmuted or muted the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to capture that event.

```js
var video = document.querySelector('video');
video.addEventListener('volumechange', function () {
    console.log('muted', video.muted);
}, false);
```

```html
<video controls autoplay muted>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below jquery event to check if the video is muted or unmuted

**volumechange** events gets triggered when user mutes or unmutes a video
**e.target.muted** returns the value true if muted and false if unmuted

```
$('video').on('volumechange',function(e){
 console.log(e.target.muted);
});
```